# Acessing a tuple value in a list (trying for hours now :( )

Tags: python, text, split

I am a Python beginner, and the task is to split a document along the same recurring line, then later to safe those parts in different files.
I split the lines and then tried to put it in tuples in a list.

```
f = open(PATENTS, 'r')
text =f.read()
n=0
counter=0
textblock=[]
stext= text.splitlines()

for lines in stext:
    if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
        textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))

    else:
        counter+=1
    n+=1
print counter
print textblock[1][1]
f.close()
```

The problem is that:

```
textblock[1][1]
```

It does not work :(

My counter works and the `if` statement does too, anyone that can give me a hint?

My file is a big text file, where each patent starts with the line that is used in the if statement. Now i want to seperate the patents from each other.

So  that i have a list that looks like this in a way :

[(0,patenttext0),(1,patenttext1)....]

Comment: Could you please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29556056/edit) to include example input/output so that we have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: And what does "not work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, post it; if not, explain how what you're getting differs from what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))`

seems you are storing a tuple inside a list.

please find out what is inside list by printing a list like this

```
print textblock
```

your list textblock must be looking something like this

```
[(1,"line1),(2,"line2"),(3,"line3")]
```

and the list is a 1D list and you are using indexing like as for a 2D array.

so please try textblock[1] not textblock[1][1]
Don't know what you are trying to acheive. but looking at your comment seems like you need to print the lines in all the tuples of your list if so then you need to iterate through all the list and print the line. you should use some loop like this.

```
line = "" 
for i in range(len(textblock)) :
       line=line+textblock[i][1]
 print line
```

Comment: textblock[1] just gives me a single line, what i want is a block of text, maybe 500 lines. they are sitting between the lines mentioned in my if statement.

Comment: I have updated my post please check. Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: So i cannot acess the value directly with one single statement, that is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the problem is but my impression is you want to print line by line along with line numbers.

The tuples you have store the line number in index 0, and the text in index 1.

In the repl for python 3:

```
>>> textBlock = []
>>> textBlock.append((1,"some text"))
>>> textBlock.append((2,"some more text"))
>>> for tuple in textBlock:
...     print(tuple[0], tuple[1])
...
1 some text
2 some more text
>>>
```

for python 2.7 replace print(...) with print tuple[0], tuple[1]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, there is no way to just acess a value in my list.

Comment: Of course you can. Your tuples are in an array. If that's what you want then to get the line number followed by the text of the first line, you'd do something like: print(textBlock[0][0], textBlock[0][1]) which prints the first element in the tuple of the first (0-based index) element in your textBlock array, and then print the second element in the same tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Python indices starts from 0, try `print textblock[0][0]`

you can also use

```
for n in range(len(stext)):
        if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
            textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))
        else:
            counter+=1
```

instead of

```
n=0
for lines in stext:
    if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
        textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))

    else:
        counter+=1
    n+=1
```

which saves the declaration and increasing of `n`

Answer (score 0):

Try this by change

```
if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
```

to

```
if lines.strip() !='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
```

**AND**

```
textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))
```

to

```
textblock.append((counter,lines)) # or lines.strip()
```

Then you have to know that

- There is no need of

  ```
  text =f.read()
  stext= text.splitlines()
  ```

  Just

  ```
  stext = f.readlines() #will get list of lines
  ```

Comment: OK, all that worked. thank you for that. Still.. i have no idea how to acess the varaible textblock :(

Comment: Ah sorry. i mispoke.. if i print textblock. i get all the text. and that is to be expected. But to now save those tuples in different file names. I need acess to a specific tuple. that is what i meant.

Comment: Sorry i dont quite understand. you mean the output ? It is like  2000 lines

Comment: [(1, '<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v44-2013-05-16.dtd" [ ]>\n'), (1, '<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.4 2013-05-16" file="USD0696836-20140107.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-pate

Comment: Then `textblock[0]` should be a tuple `(1,"string")`.Also `textblock[0][0]` should be `1`. and so on..

Comment: OK.. but it  simply is not. When i use textblock[0] or any number, i always just get (1, and then one line of code). I simply dont understand what i do so wrong

Comment: So may be 1st element of every tuple is 1. Did you check other than 1 in `testblock`?

Comment: if i print out my counter at th end, it is at 4. so clearly it is counting up. So i dont understand how every first element of the tuples could possibly be one :(

Comment: Counter is not counting in `if` but `else`.So not it is very clear evidence.You have to check again that file.

Comment: check with `print set(i[0] for i in testblock)`

Comment: that gives me an output of : set([1, 2, 3, 4])

Comment: Kk..so there is tuple with other than 1..`print [i for i in testblock if i[0] in (2,3,4)]`